# Cookies or Session? Which one should I use for my project?

Tags: php, apache, session, cookies

I have a complete login system in PHP using Sessions, which works like this

```
<?php

if(isset($_SESSION['user_id']))
{
  //lets the user use their profile
}
else
{
 //takes the user to the login page
}

?>
```

It works fine on my local server (XAMPP) as doesn't logout the user. Which means the session wasn't destroyed. But when I use the same system on a live server which is a Linux(Ubuntu) server, it destroys the session when I close the browser. I've tried extending the session lifetime but it doesn't work. I know this is how Sessions are supposed to work.

But, want to keep users logged in like on Facebook(on a mobile browser). I know I can use cookies for that but, cookies shouldn't be used to save information like user name and password.

What should I do? any suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

You should use sessions with cookies... it's pretty much the standard way today.

The cookie only stores the session id. A session isn't destroyed, it "expires" (this means the session cookie, not the session itself).

Comment: I'm still a newbie so, can you elaborate a bit? Like the session holds the `user_id` ... That has to match with the record on the database. Am I suppose the save the session in a cookie?

Comment: Session only exists on the server-side, all data is stored only there. The session id is only the identifier for the session under which the data is found. If the cookie expires, session id isn't sent to the server, which then leads to the creation of a new session. But the data (usually a file) is still present...